# OWB: Problem integrating external database with JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, data-warehouse

we're currently building a data warehouse using OWB (Oracle Warehouse Builder).
One of the DCS (data capturing systems) is a proprietary database (PI by Osisoft Inc); we want to integrate it using JDBC.

The repository is located on a Linux system (RHEL 5.3, Oracle 11.2.0.2, OWB 11.2.0.2), 
I'm connecting from a Windows XP system (OWB 11.2.0.2).

According to the OWB documentation, I should copy the JDBC jar file to 
$OWB_HOME/owb/lib/ext, add a new platform (using OMB+) and then add a new location.

I've tried this with SQLite, and everything seems ok, but with PI, "Test connection" in OWB doesn't give me any feedback, and when I try to get the list of tables/views from the source system, it hangs.

Some questions regarding this:

- is the JDBC jar file required on the "Server" side (RHEL 5.3) or "Client" side (Windows XP) (sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, I'm still getting started with OWB)?
- the JDBC driver requires a .dll (Win) / .so (Linux); is this possible with OWB? Or does OWB accept only "pure" JDBC drivers?
- is there any possibility to debug the JDBC access (some kind of log file, perhaps)?

I'd be thankful for any hints on solving this.

Kind regards
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we couldn't get this to work, we changed our approach:

- OWB calls a user defined activity A1
- A1 executes a shell script S1 on the Linux server
- S1 calls a small java program J1 (with the classpath settings etc.)
- J1 connects to the proprietary database using JDBC, fetches the data and writes it to a .csv file
- OWB then loads this .csv file using an external table

Kind regards
Frank